# Replace element tags using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need parse my document. I mean I want to replace "div" to for example "p"

so the code:

```
<section class="X">
<p>Some title</p>
<div data-newname="p"></div>
</section>
```

becomes to:

```
<section class="X">
<p>Some title</p>
<p></p> <- here is replacement 
</section>
```

So the point is, I need to find element by data-attribute and replace start (`<div>`) and end (`</div>`) to anything i want to.

but I dont have idea how can I do this. I have many divs element with data attribute and I need to replace  to {{Start::test}}{{End::test}} - the test is from data-attribute, or whatever..

I will be grateful for any help from you guys..

Comment: Is there nothing that will uniquely identify the element to be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery you could use https://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/ and return a brand new jQuery Element Object

```js
$('[data-newname]').replaceWith(function() {
  const tagName = $(this).data('newname')
  return $(`<${tagName}/>`, {text: 'demo'});
});
```

```css
p {padding: 10px; outline: 1px solid red;}
```

```html
<section class="X">
  <p>Some title</p>
  <div data-newname="p"></div>
</section>


<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and inside the `{}` you can pass any available Method you like (see example above using jQuery's `text` Method)

#### Keep the content

if you want to keep the content you can similarly do:

```js
$('[data-newname]').replaceWith(function() {
  const tagName = $(this).data('newname')
  return $(`<${tagName}/>`, {html: $(this).html()});
});
```

```css
p {padding: 10px; outline: 1px solid red;}
```

```html
<section class="X">
  <p>Some title</p>
  <div data-newname="p">Lorem <b>ipsum</b> <i>dolor</i></div>
  <div data-newname="marquee">This still works wohaa</div>
</section>


<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

P.S:
don't get confused by this

```
$(`<${tagName}/>\`,
```

it's just the same as `$('<'+ tagName +'/>',` just using Template Literal and inserting a variable into the string using the placeholder `${}`

https://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals